# Get internal attributes with Spring LDAP

Tags: java, ldap, spring-ldap

I'm using **Spring LDAP 1.3.0** library to access an internal LDAP server, with Java, but I'm having troubles to do one thing: how can I get an internal attribute of any structure of LDAP? For example, how can I get the **memberOf** attribute of an user?

I ever searched a lot but don't find anything about that using Spring LDAP.
Any ideas will be very welcome. Thanks.

Comment: I found a way and it's very simple. Example:

_getLdapTemplate().search( "dc=MY_COMPANY,dc=com,dc=br", "(&(objectClass=person)(uid=USER_UID))", SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE, new String[]{ "memberOf" }, new UserAttributeMapper() );_

Observation: in this code, the **UserAttributeMapper** is just my own implementation of **org.springframework.ldap.core.AttributesMapper**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Spring LDAP's LdapTemplate not return title, department & company attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45295527/why-does-spring-ldaps-ldaptemplate-not-return-title-department-company-attri)

Answer (score 4):

As you said in comment **UserAttributeMapper** is your friend !

If the user has more than one 'memberof' :

```
    static List<List<String>> getPersonGroupsByAccountName(String accountName){

    EqualsFilter filter = new EqualsFilter("sAMAccountName", accountName);
    return ldap.search(DistinguishedName.EMPTY_PATH,filter.encode(),new AttributesMapper(){
        public Object mapFromAttributes(
                javax.naming.directory.Attributes attrs)
        throws javax.naming.NamingException {
            List<String> memberof = new ArrayList();
            for (Enumeration vals = attrs.get("memberOf").getAll(); vals.hasMoreElements();) {
                memberof.add((String)vals.nextElement());
            }
            return memberof;
        }
    });
```

I'm sure there is a better way to do this but it works.

Comment: Thank you! Of all the search results of all the posts this was the only one that worked for me. +1.

Comment: I’m glad it was helpful for you !

Answer (score 1):

I use this to get fields like "createTimestamp" or "pwdChangedTime",
and UserContextMapper you can reference resources: http://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/1.3.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/

```
ldapTemplate.lookup(dn, new String[] {"*", "+"}, new UserContextMapper());
```

Answer (score 0):

It also works with odmManager. Something like

```
DistinguishedName dn = new DistinguishedName("The path your are searching in");
SearchControls searchControls = new SearchControls();
searchControls.setReturningObjFlag(true);
searchControls.setReturningAttributes("your attributes, as an array of strings");
return odmManager.findAll(User.class, dn, searchControls);
```

I use this to get fields like "createTimestamp" ....