# Why does Spring LDAP's LdapTemplate not return title, department & company attributes?

Tags: spring-mvc, active-directory, jndi, spring-ldap, ldap-query

I'm using `spring-ldap-core-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar` over `JDK 1.8` & `Tomcat 8.0` to access AD information through `LdapTemplate`. The attributes such as `title`,`department` & `company` are not being returned by the `ldapTemplate.search(..,.,..)` method.

I'm using the following lines of code to search :-

```
LdapQuery ldapQuery = LdapQueryBuilder.query()
                                       .where("objectclass").is("user")
                                       .and("objectcategory").is("person")
                                       .and("cn").like(strWildcardText+"*");
ldapTemplate.search(ldapQuery, new ADUserAttributesMapper());
```

Following is the `ADUserAttributesMapper` class :-

```
public class ADUserAttributesMapper implements AttributesMapper<ADUserBean> {
    @Override
    public ADUserBean mapFromAttributes(Attributes attributes) throws NamingException {
        if(attributes==null) {
            return null;
        }

        adUserBean.setName((attributes.get("name")!=null) ? attributes.get("name").get().toString() : null);
        adUserBean.setCommonName((attributes.get("cn")!=null) ? attributes.get("cn").get().toString() : null);
        adUserBean.setDisplayName((attributes.get("displayname")!=null) ? attributes.get("displayname").get().toString() : null);
        adUserBean.setGivenName((attributes.get("givenname")!=null) ? attributes.get("givenname").get().toString() : null); // for FIRST NAME
        adUserBean.setMiddleName((attributes.get("initials")!=null) ? attributes.get("initials").get().toString() : null); // for MIDDLE NAME / INITIALS
        adUserBean.setLastName((attributes.get("sn")!=null) ? attributes.get("sn").get().toString() : null); // for LAST NAME
        adUserBean.setDepartment((attributes.get("department")!=null) ? attributes.get("department").get().toString() : null);
        adUserBean.setUserPrincipalName((attributes.get("userprincipalname")!=null) ? attributes.get("userprincipalname").get().toString() : null); // Logon Name
        adUserBean.setsAMAccountName((attributes.get("samaccountname")!=null) ? attributes.get("samaccountname").get().toString() : null); // Logon Name (pre-Windows 2000)
        adUserBean.setDistinguishedName((attributes.get("distinguishedname")!=null) ? attributes.get("distinguishedname").get().toString() : null);
        adUserBean.setMailID((attributes.get("mail")!=null) ? attributes.get("mail").get().toString() : null);
        adUserBean.setTitle((attributes.get("title")!=null) ? attributes.get("title").get().toString() : null); // Job Title
        adUserBean.setTelephoneNumber((attributes.get("telephonenumber")!=null) ? attributes.get("telephonenumber").get().toString() : null);
        adUserBean.setObjectCategory((attributes.get("objectcategory")!=null) ? attributes.get("objectcategory").get().toString() : null);

        return adUserBean;
    }
}
```

The `title`,`department` & `company` attributes belong to the **Organization** tab of the AD user properties as shown in the below image :-
[image]

Also, from the **General** tab the initials(`initials`) attribute is not being picked up/listed by Spring-LDAP's `ldapTemplate`. The `LdapQueryBuilder.query()` object has access to `attributes(...)` method that takes a string array of attribute names that are to be fetched. But even after mentioning them there explicitly, values for attributes such as `initials`, `title`, `department` & `company` are not returned.

The **LDAP Browser** plugin within the Eclipse IDE lists the `title`,`department` & `company` properties under the **Organization** tab without a problem.

Even the `com4j` API returns the `title`, `department` & `company` attributes.

Is there any configuration that is limiting the attribute(s) listing or is it a limitation with Spring-LDAP API itself? Are these attributes not part of `BasicAttributes`? How to fetch these attributes through Spring-LDAP?

**UPDATE (01-Aug-2017):**
The plain **Java JNDI** approach/code does NOT return `department`,`company`,`title` attributes (even with these attributes being explicitly mentioned in attributes string array), but surprisingly it does return the `initials` attribute value.

**UPDATE (02-Aug-2017):**
Similar to @Pierre's suggestion (below) tried the following code using `SearchControls` object :-

```
String strFilter= "(&(objectclass=top)(cn=cgma*))";
String[] attrs = new String[] {"cn","givenName","sn","initials","title","department","company"};
long maxResults = 10; // for example 
SearchControls searchControls = new SearchControls();
searchControls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
searchControls.setReturningAttributes(attrs);
searchControls.setCountLimit(maxResults);
List<String> aLstOfADUsers = ldapTemplate.search("",strFilter,searchControls,new AttributesMapper<String>() 
                                                                     {
                                                                        public String mapFromAttributes(Attributes attrs) throws NamingException {
                                                                            try
                                                                            {
                                                                                System.out.println(attrs.toString());
                                                                                return attrs.get("cn").get().toString();
                                                                            }
                                                                            catch(Exception ex) {
                                                                                ex.printStackTrace();
                                                                                return null;
                                                                            }
                                                                        }
                                                                     });

return aLstOfADUsers;
```

Even this **does not** return the `initials`, `title`, `company` & `department` attribute values.

Answer (score 6):

The person attributes might be internal attributes which you wouldn't get back by default. You can specify explicitly which attributes you want returned BUT not in the search method you're using (the one where you pass in an LdapQuery object). If you take a look at the org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate class, it doesn't seem like you can pass in the SearchControls object to the method signature you're using. So, to be able to specify attributes to fetch, replace this:

```
LdapQuery ldapQuery = LdapQueryBuilder.query()
                                       .where("objectclass").is("user")
                                       .and("objectcategory").is("person")
                                       .and("cn").like(strWildcardText+"*");
ldapTemplate.search(ldapQuery, new ADUserAttributesMapper());
```

With this:

```
        LikeFilter filter = new LikeFilter("cn", strWildcardText+"*");

        // list of attributes to retrieve
        String[] attrs = new String[] {"title","department","company"};
        long maxResults = 10; // for example 

        SearchControls searchControls = new SearchControls();
        searchControls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
        searchControls.setReturningAttributes(attrs);
        searchControls.setCountLimit(numResults);

        ldapTemplate.search(DistinguishedName.EMPTY_PATH, filter.encode(), searchControls, new ADUserAttributesMapper());
```

The above should work. You could also try something like this (I haven't tried that yet):

```
ldapTemplate.search( "dc=yourorg,dc=com", 
        "(&(cn=" +strWildcardText + "*)(&(objectClass=person)(objectcategory=person)))",
        SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE,
        new String[]{ "title","department","company" },
        new ADUserAttributesMapper() );
```

Finally, to get ALL attributes back, ask to retrieve ALL attributes in the code above (my above example only asked for 3 attributes, this would return ALL of them):

```
        String[] attrs = new String[]{"*","+"};
```

Comment: Hi Perre, thanx for responding. I tried your suggested code but it throws `null` pointer exception and also the class `DistinguishedName`is deprecated.

Comment: Please see **UPDATE (02-Aug-2017)**, above in the question area.

Comment: @Shiva : I'm trying to think of other possibilities and one that comes to mind is that maybe you're connecting to a Domain Controller (DC) that does not have all these attributes. Can you confirm that the URL you use to connect to LDAP is the same in your code as the one in your screenshot of your LDAPBrowser? If not, look into that. Otherwise, I'm not sure what's wrong, that attribute should really be there...

Comment: @Shiva: yes, DistinguishedName is deprecated but wanted to see if that old way of doing things worked. Where do you get the null pointer exception?

Comment: Shiva: yet another suggestion to try: use a contextMapper instead of an attributeMapper and see what you can get (maybe use the debugger to inspect what's returned/available). Ex: new ContextMapper(){  
        @Override  
        public Object mapFromContext(Object ctx)  
        {  
            DirContextAdapter context = (DirContextAdapter)ctx;  
            adUserBean.setTitle(context.getStringAttributes("title");  
        } });

Answer (score 1):

This is based on your `AttributesMapper`.  I don't know what `ADUserAttributesMapper` is, so you'd have to provide that implementation.

Here's the javadoc for this interface.  http://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/ldap/core/AttributesMapper.html

Comment: Hi Ryan, thanx for responding. Here, `ADUserAttributesMapper` is a class that implements `org.springframework.ldap.core.AttributesMapper` interface. It maps the fetched attributes to the properties of a Java POJO bean. Does this limit the number of attributes returned from the LDAP query search? Is there any other mapper?

Comment: Can you update your question to include this implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Change ldap port from 3268 to 389